# Netstat flags on OS/2

Tags: routing, netstat, flags, ibm

On an OS/2 box, what do the flags UGDP mean in the output of netstat -r. Google seems to point to them meaning Up, Gateway (i.e. an indirect root), and Dynamic (learned from a redirect), but that leaves me mystified as to the meaning of P. The only suggestion I've had is permanent but that doesn't make any sense with dynamic. Any ideas?

Comment: os/2? wow. I didn't know anyone still ran it :)

Comment: I thought that too up until recently :-(

Comment: There should really be a badge for someone who sets a new tag that hasn't been used before, especially if it's for something antique. "Dusty", perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the 'P' is for persistent

Comment: I assumed that as well, but that doesn't make any sense if 'D' is dynamic, does it?